# nxginx proxy https site?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have a secure website that I would like to proxy behind nginx.  Is this possible?  How?

So, it will be like this:

Client --> https --> nginx --> htts --> other site

I have seen others ask the same question but have been unable to find a definitive answer.

Thanks!

EV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to setup SSL on your nginx, which means that you need an SSL certificate and the [configs for nginx to support SSL](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule). Then you add a proxy pass rule like

```
proxy_pass https://exapmle.com:443
```

I haven't tested it yet but maybe it works